# Does apt-get stop working after support ends?

Tags: apt

I have a system with Ubuntu 10.10, and many packages will not install with apt-get anymore (the error says "not found IP") although those packages still install under 10.04 LTS. (This is after performing "apt-get update")

So is that what happens after support for a version like 10.10 expires?  Is the repository no longer maintained so that we can't "apt-get install" anymore?   If so, when will that happen to 10.04?  Or is there something I can do to keep it from breaking?

(please no comments about how I need to update to the latest version, I have reasons for needing to keep older versions active as well)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is centered around updates. In order to trick people into upgrading to the newest version of Ubuntu rather than using an unsupported release, they like to move the repositories. They do the same thing with ubuntu iso downloads. You can update your sources.list to use the new location, then everything will work.

In terminal type: sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

Change all the ubuntu.com entries so that they start with http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ . You may end up with some duplicate entries. After editing open the terminal and type "sudo apt-get update". You are now ready to install software again.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks.  Just curious though, is there some point when the "old releases" repository may stop working as well?   Are the "old releases" repositories still working for the real old Ubuntu versions like Warty from 2004?

Comment: I'm not sure how long the old releases repos are kept for. The oldest I've tested is 10.10.