# 404 not found - error while updating using aptitude

Tags: 13.04, apt

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
```

Comment: 13.04 is no longer supported, You need to upgrade to a supported version to use apt. In fact, even support for 13.10 will be dropped today.

Comment: Check the following question/answer for a more details:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/405699/does-apt-get-stop-working-after-support-ends/405703#405703

Answer (score 3):

When you run it, `apt-get` is not able to find the directory in the server.

With a browser you can try to follow the link `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages` and you will find an error because it doesn't exist anymore the directory.

If you rise the path you will have the first non error page in  `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/`. From here you can see which are the distribution you can still download.

So you can edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and substitute all the repository like `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/` with

1. `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/`  **to switch to a supported one**. It is the 14.04 LTS, or Trusty Tahr, supported till April 2019...
2. `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/`  **to change source to the old one**.

**A suggestion: `dist-upgrade` as you can.**

---

If you need to remain with the old version, as suggested by [diogo-melo](https://askubuntu.com/users/80719/diogo-melo), you can change your source list doing the replacement  with the command:

> **sudo** sed -i 's/archive.ubuntu/old-releases.ubuntu/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

I strongly recommend to do in advance a backup copy of your `source.list` file

```
 sudo cp -i  /etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.old
```

It will prompt in case `sources.list.old` already exists and, in this case, feel you free to use another name for the backup copy.